# I faced with this error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(Sample.a);   
    }
}


class Sample{
   
     static int a = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println(a);
    
    }
}
```

I faced with error:

```
cannot find symbol
System.out.println(Sample.a);
symbol: variable Sample
location: class Example
```

So that how to solve this error?

Comment: make `a` public

Comment: are these in different files?  Probably just make `Sample` public

Comment: did you (re-)compile the Example class before compiling the Sample class?

Comment: these are in same same folders but I made Sample as public, the same error appeared.

Comment: I compiled Example class before Sample class and as well as after Sample class the same error appeared.

Comment: the java version is the latest version 18 and edit plus version is 5.5

Comment: and the windows version is 7

Comment: please show the command that you are using to compile.

Comment: @ScaryWombat:                                                                                                                          javac Example.java

Comment: @HazratWaliKhadem the only way I can reproduce this is by giving the wrong file name to `Sample.java` (by calling it `SSample.java` for example). Did you name the files correctly?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I recheck the name of .class file and .java file and the name given in Example class are same and the names are correct.

Comment: @HazratWaliKhadem last idea: try and delete both .class files and recompile

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I did so but still did not get result.

Comment: OP, *delete both .class files* - why is there two class files if one does not compile - something strange going on here.  Why not use a IDE?

Answer (score 1):

create 2 separate files. Each for 1 class. It is neat that way. Make them in the same directory so you don't need to import anything.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(Sample.a);
    }
}
```

then in class Sample, make 'a' public

```
public class Sample {
    public static int a = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

Comment: they are separate classes and are in same folder as well, I made the Sample class and static variable a as public as well.

Comment: have you recompiled it? 
it works at my pc. Try troubleshooting a bit based on the error information

Comment: I recompiled many times  it is not working in my pc, I do not know what is the problem actually?

Comment: try asking a senior/colleague around you. Faster that way

Comment: @Hazrat Wali Khadem Then you should compare the class "Sample" provided in the answer to the class "Sample" that you have shown in your question. There is a detail in the former that enables the code to compile.